# What is a Computer Phrase™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, english, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a phrase conforms to a special rule, I call it a Computer Phrase™.  Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Computer Phrases™ | Not Computer Phrases™ |
| --- | --- |
| VERY FUN DAY | TRULY BORING DAY |
| SOME ZIPPED UP DISK DRIVES | A CIRCUIT BOARD |
| KILL A FLY | CATCH A BUTTERFLY |
| IN YOUR FACE! | IN HIS FACE! |
| GO LAY HOLD | GO LIE DOWN |
| A HIGH SCHOOL BOY | A HARD SCHOOL DAY |
| IT CAN BE GOOD FOR HER | THAT MAY BE GOOD FOR HIM |
| THE EMAIL LIST | THE PHONE BOOK |
| HEY HEY! | HELLO HELLO! |
| DID MY JACKET GET BLOODY? | A BAT EARED FOX |
| IN THE DARK HOUR | IN THE DARKEST HOUR |

CSV version:

```
Computer Phrases™,          Not Computer Phrases™
VERY FUN DAY,               TRULY BORING DAY
SOME ZIPPED UP DISK DRIVES, A CIRCUIT BOARD
KILL A FLY,                 CATCH A BUTTERFLY
IN YOUR FACE!,              IN HIS FACE!
GO LAY HOLD,                GO LIE DOWN
A HIGH SCHOOL BOY,          A HARD SCHOOL DAY
IT CAN BE GOOD FOR HER,     THAT MAY BE GOOD FOR HIM
THE EMAIL LIST,             THE PHONE BOOK
HEY HEY!,                   HELLO HELLO!
DID MY JACKET GET BLOODY?,  A BAT EARED FOX
IN THE DARK HOUR,           IN THE DARKEST HOUR
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption that each phrase can be tested for whether it is a Computer Phrase™ without relying on the other phrases. These are not the only examples of Computer Phrases™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these phrases conform to?**

---

Hint:

> One word from each phrase is extra and can be removed.

Hint 2:

> Some numbers are special to Computer Scientists and are relevant in this puzzle.

Hint 3:

> The first word from each phrase can be ignored.

Comment: I can't shake the suspicion that this has something to do with rot13(Xensgjrex).

Comment: What? The electronic band???

Comment: Does it relates to the keyboard?

Comment: @CulverKwan Added hints. Keyboard is not related.

Comment: @DenverCoder1, you've been editing a lot of your old posts all at once - is it possible to stop for a day or so? The Active page is flooded at this point.

Comment: @bobble Sorry about that. Just had the idea to convert my posts to markdown after a few had been converted by other users. I think I'm done for now, but I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:

> A Computer Phrase™ is a phrase that **the A1Z26 of the first letters of the words concatenated**(excluding the first word) equals **2 to the power of the sum of the length of the words**(excluding the first word).

Explanation:

For the Computer Phrases™:

> VERY FUN DAY -> F, D -> 6-4 -> **2**6**, "FUN DAY" has **6** letters
> SOME ZIPPED UP DISK DRIVES -> Z, U, D, D -> 26-21-4-4 -> **2**18**, "ZIPPED UP DISK DRIVES" has **18** letters
> KILL A FLY -> A, F -> 1-6 -> **2**4**, "A FLY" has **4** letters
> IN YOUR FACE! -> Y, F -> 25-6 -> **2**8**, "YOUR FACE" has **8** letters
> GO LAY HOLD -> L, H -> 12-8 -> **2**7**, "LAY HOLD" has **7** letters
> A HIGH SCHOOL BOY -> H, S, B -> 8-19-2 -> **2**13**, "HIGH SCHOOL BOY" has **13** letters
> IT CAN BE GOOD FOR HER -> C, B, G, F, H -> 3-2-7-6-8 -> **2**15**, "CAN BE GOOD FOR HER" has **15** letters
> THE EMAIL LIST -> E, L -> 5-12 -> **2**9**, "EMAIL LIST" has **9** letters
> HEY HEY! -> H -> 8 -> **2**3**, "HEY" has **3** letters
> DID MY JACKET GET BLOODY? -> M, J, G, B -> 13-10-7-2 -> **2**17**, "MY JACKET GET BLOODY" has **17** letters
> IN THE DARK HOUR -> T, D, H -> 20-4-8 -> **2**11**, "THE DARK HOUR" has **11** letters

For the Non-Computer Phrases™:

> TRULY BORING DAY -> B, D -> 2-4
> A CIRCUIT BOARD -> C, B -> 3-2 -> 2**5, but "CIRCUIT BOARD" has 12 letters
> CATCH A BUTTERFLY -> A, B -> 1-2
> IN HIS FACE! -> H, F -> 8-6
> GO LIE DOWN -> L, D -> 12-4
> A HARD SCHOOL DAY -> H, S, D -> 8-19-4
> THAT MAY BE GOOD FOR HIM -> M, B, G, F, H -> 13-2-7-6-8
> THE PHONE BOOK -> P, B -> 16-2
> HELLO HELLO! -> H -> 8 -> 2**3, but "HELLO" has 5 letters
> A BAT EARED FOX -> B, E, F -> 2-5-6 -> 2**8, but "BAT EARED FOX" has 11 letters
> IN THE DARKEST HOUR -> T, D, H -> 20-4-8 -> 2**11, but "THE DARKEST HOUR" has 14 letters

It is called Computer Phrases™ because:

> Binary is important for computers.